# URI Response Code

Tags: ruby, url, open-uri

I would like to use Ruby's [OpenURI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html) to check whether the URL can be properly accessed. So I would like to check its response code (4xx or 5xx means error, etc.) Is it possible to find that?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use the [`status`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI/Meta.html) method to return an array that contains the status code and message.

```
require "open-uri" 

open("http://www.example.org") do |f|
  puts f.base_uri  #=> http://www.example.org
  puts f.status    #=> ["200", "OK"]
end
```

Comment: Note that `f.status` returns an array, the first element being the response code and the second being the response status. Both elements are Ruby `String`s.

Comment: Just tried this for a 403 and it gives an exception, so I'm not sure if it can be used in general...